# A View Is Not Being Removed From All Of The Views After Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've got a super class that I made called protected view. It segregates content based on whether or not a user is logged in or not. I'm using FireBase for user authentication. I can confirm users are authenticated based on my login methods but when I do `user.removeFromSuperView`, the view does not go away. I'm calling `checkAuthentication()` in my `viewdidload` of the super class where the whole function exists.

```
let bannerView = ForceSignInBanner.instanceFromNib() as! ForceSignInBanner
bannerView.delegate = self

if (!AuthenticationService.sharedInstance.isAuthenticated()) {
    print("Sign them up")
    self.view.addSubview(bannerView)

} else if(AuthenticationService.sharedInstance.isAuthenticated()){
    bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is imperative so it only works at the moment viewDidLoad is called not later in the view controller's lifetime. In order to handle this correctly you need to use `addStateDidChangeListener`. As in:

```
self.bannerView = ForceSignInBanner.instanceFromNib() as! ForceSignInBanner
bannerView.delegate = self

handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [unowned self] (_, user) in
    if user != nil {
        self.bannerView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    else {
        self.view.addSubview(self.bannerView)
    }
}
```

This way the closure is called any time the authorization state of the user changes.

Comment: what or where did you get handle? are you just declaring that as a var or let earlier? Also thanks for the help.

Comment: `handle` is a var that is declared on the view controller (along with `bannerView`). It is used to "turn off" the listener when you don't want to listen anymore. Learn more at https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start